# sending data from arduino to node js backend server

Tags: node.js, arduino

i have project in which i need to send my data from my arduino to my backend server node js
it's my first time using uhf RFID and node js
i need to read uhf rfid tag using uhf rfid rader and arduino IDE and sending this (uid tag) to my backend server node js express
i'm using esp32 nodemcu board
please can anyone help me with informations or documentations , how to read uhf rfid tag and how to send it to node js server

Answer (score 0):

Once you are sure that ESP32 is connected to the internet (by wifi for example), you need to handle your arduino as a HTTP client. This way, you will need to make requests to the server, as you would make in the browser or Postman, for example.

You can check how to make a HTTP client arduino [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/httpclient/).

Comment: thank you verry much , how to receive the post request in my node js backend server ? when i Use HTTP can i send data in Real time ?

Comment: if you made your backend using NodeJS and express, it is just to implement a [.post route](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). But HTTP is kind syncronous, not realtime. To use realtime, you may use another kind of protocol with a persistent connection, such MQTT or even raw tcp (note HTTP is above TCP layer but not persistent).